# command prompt does not allow me to use docker and mysql functions at the same time for creating an sql database in docker container

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, command-prompt

I start by saying that I am new to the docker and mysql functions for creating containers with a volume.
In this case I need to import a .sql file called **database_stage.sql**, which is a database of a web page created by me through web hosting using the Pantheon service. I need to import this database from a folder on the desktop within the volume which is attached to my container in docker desktop. When I want to start this command through the command prompt, it opens the mysql help page for me. In addition I mention that I am not able to use both the docker and mysql functions together and I don't understand why.
*So my question is the following. Why don't you run the command to me, without showing some kind of error on the screen?*
the command line is as follows:

```
docker exec -i <my_ID_Container> mysql -u root -p password <db_name> < <database_to_import>


docker exec -i 816f46df4f59 mysql -uroot -psecret database_stage < cartella_database/database_stage.sql
```

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNn14.png)

todos is the name of my database taken inside my Docker-compose file.

below I am attaching some images of the command prompt:

[command *docker ps* to explain the immage container ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r60ra.png)

the command prompt explain me this:

[command prompt mysql help page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPMvo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer for myself because it can serve as an answer to someone else who will have this problem.I created another database using the mysql commands:

`create database database_stage`

and I created a folder specifically named *database_folder* in the *docker.compose file directory*

In which I moved the *database_stage.sql* file, then I changed the directory requested in the command after the sign **<** and I only received a warning because I set the password using the command.

---

I didn't understand the real problem but this is how it works ...

**(I updated the code in the response with the current and working one)**